# Looking best form to make One Way Binding between directives

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I have this **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iu6Eu5nWEl2SAuAvXUYe?p=preview)**

I would like to know if there is a way to make one way binding between directives?

I had a father directive and his son. i want to send to the child an object (or model), and when the child receive this and show the object over the inputs, if I modify any input field; the father doesn't listen those changes.

I decide use angular.copy, to modify over this new copy and just when i do ng-click. The Child send the new object to the father ('&').

```
myApp.directive('oneWayBinding', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      datasource: '=',
      add: '&'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {

      $scope.newName = {};

      $scope.init = function(datasource) {
        angular.copy($scope.datasource, $scope.newName);
      };

      $scope.init();

      $scope.senFather = function(){
        $scope.add({newName:$scope.newName});
      };

    },
    template: '<h3>Directive</h3>' +
                  '<label>Nombre y Apellido: </label>' +
                  '<input ng-model="newName.name"><input ng-model="newName.apellido"><button ng-click="senFather()">Send Father</button><br>'
  };

});
```

There is another method or form to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the term "One way binding", but yes, this is way, which is usually used to isolate change.